# Krull-Akizuki theorem for Noetherian reduced rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Wikipedia article about [Krull-Akizuki theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Akizuki_theorem) gives a very general version of theorem: let *A* be a one-dimensional reduced noetherian ring, *K* its total ring of fractions. If *B* is a subring of a finite extension *L* of *K* containing *A* and is not a field, then *B* is a one-dimensional noetherian ring. Furthermore, for every nonzero ideal *I* of *B*, *B*/*I* is finite over *A*.

Unfortunately I can't find anywhere else such a statement. Typically statement is as above but for noetherian domains and finite extensions of fields of fractions. That includes Bourbaki's *Commutative algebra*, that is given as a reference in Wikipedias article, Matsumura *Commutative ring theory* and number of others.

Proof that is given in Wikipedia is only for the case *L* = *K* and is taken from Huneke & Swanson *Integral Closure of Ideals, Rings, and Modules*. There theorem stated for noetherian reduced rings but again only for *L* = *K*.

So is general statement from Wikipedia correct? Are there some references or am I missing something and it can be reduced to case of domains?

Thank you!

Comment: I hope you mean that $A\subset B$, otherwise what you state is false. Assuming this, can you reduce it to the case when $L=K$?

Comment: Yes, Mohan $A \subset B$ (there is given that *B* contains *A*). Still statement in Wikipedia is not correct, is it? If  *A* is not domain its total ring of fractions is not a field, but it is artinian and has dimension 0. In Huneke & Swanson  there is condition that *B* is not equal to *K*.

Comment: Reducing it to the case when *L* =  *K* is what I'm trying to do. Idea is that if *L* is finite ring extension then there is finite generating set $a_1,...,a_n$ of *L* as *K*-module. Looking at their multiplication table and multiplying denominators it is possible to take $b_i = pa_i$ where *p* is not zero divisor of *A* and *A*-module generated by 1 and $b_i$ will be a ring. So will be *B*-module generated by 1 and $b_i$. They will be finite extensions so will be noetherian iff *A*, *B* are and will have the same dimension. Also *L* is total ring of fractions of this extension of *A*.

Comment: So thats how it an be reduced to the case *L* = *K*. Is it correct?

Comment: Good, you have the idea.